# Trigger to generate uniqued ID before insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

quite an easy question, but how to create a trigger in MySQL which before insert generates unique Id's for 'ID' column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for that. Simply set the column with the "auto_increment" option in the table structure.

[Documentation for auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Hero! take a look at this ;) [link](http://memearchive.net/memerial.net/679/pikachu-army.jpg)